# Move differentiation before integral in DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following system of differential equations with `DSolve`
$$
\partial_y f(x,y) = \partial_x g(x,y) \; ,\\
\partial_y g(x,y) = 0 \; ,
$$
with a boundary condition of $f(x,0)=0$. I'm expecting a solution like
$$
f(x,y) = y \partial_x g(x,y) \; .
$$
However, when I ask Mathematica to execute the following

```
DSolve[{
  (* Differential equations *)
  D[f[x, y], y] == D[g[x, y], x],
  D[g[x, y], y] == 0,
  (* Conditions *)
  f[x, 0] == 0
  }, {f[x, y], g[x, y]}, y]
```

it gives the following answer
$$
\left\{\left\{f(x,y)\to \int_1^y g^{(1,0)}(x,K[1]) \, dK[1]-\int_1^0 g^{(1,0)}(x,K[1]) \, dK[1],g(x,y)\to c_2\right\}\right\}
$$
These integrals could be solved using Leibniz rule.

How can I tell Mathematica to solve also these integrals?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But according to the second equation in the system the term $y g_{xy}$ vanishes and it is a solution or am I missing something.

Comment: OK, that seems right.  I think the problem is that `DSolve` is treating `x` as a constant parameter, because you specify only `y` as an independent variable.  See if my answer is helpful (and correct). :)

Answer (score 1):

I think one problem is that you ask `DSolve` to solve the system as an ODE system by specifying only one independent variable `y`.  That is why, for instance, the solution for `g` is a constant, instead of a function of `x` only.

Turning it into a PDE by changing the independent variables to `{x, y}` results in a `DSolve` that returns unevaluated.  However, differentiating the second equation results in a solvable system.  The only inconvenience is then to impose on the solution that it satisfy the undifferentiated equation.

```
{ddsol} = DSolve[{
    (*Differential equations*)
    D[f[x, y], y] == D[g[x, y], x],
    D[g[x, y], y, x] == 0,
    (*Conditions*)
    f[x, 0] == 0},
   {f, g}, {x, y}];
(* imposed the condition  D[g[x, y], y] == 0  *)
{gsol} = DSolve[Equal @@@ First@Solve[D[g[x, y], y] == 0 /. ddsol], C[3][y], y];
dsol = ddsol /. gsol (* final solution *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see that the solution satisfies the equations, where `C[2]` represents an arbitrary (sufficiently smooth) function.

```
{D[f[x, y], y], D[g[x, y], x]} /. dsol
D[g[x, y], y] /. dsol
f[x, 0] /. dsol
(*
  {C[2][x], C[2][x]}
  0
  0
*)
```

Further, it has the form expected by the OP since

```
D[g[x, y], x] /. dsol
(*  C[2][x]  *)
```

*Note:*
I had to inspect `ddsol` to determine that `C[3]` was the variable to use to find `gsol`:

```
ddsol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]